# Translation of "emotional turmoil"

Tags: перевод

What's the russian equivalent for ***emotional turmoil / turmoil of emotions***?

For instance when a man and a woman just fell in love with each other?

I couldn't find something in common dictionaries.

Comment: I wouldn't use _emotional turmoil_ to describe the feelings of falling in love - but rather the opposite. You could be in an emotional turmoil after a fight with your other half, for example.

Comment: While the given answer by Shady_arc is correct, the quality  of translation depends not only on picking the right phrase, but also on how it fits in the sentence. You may end up with a translation that conforms to rules but is not idiomatic. Poets often have to change the meaning slightly so that they are still painting a picture and conveying emotions rather than mechanically reporting what is going on. Consider phrases like "Огнедышащим вихрем любви ..." The following pop song is a bit cheesy, but it illustrates metaphors for passionate love  http://www.karaoke.ru/catalog/song/30741/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

err... **"буря чувств/эмоций"** may suit. Maybe even all too easy a solution. Such things are highly dependent on the sentence you want to use it in.

Comment: So ***буря чувств/эмоций*** would fit in the given example case?

Comment: Yeah, it would,